# Drawing a large graph with sigmajs

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Drawing a graph with 10000 nodes with sigmajs. The problem is that all the nodes are cramped in one space and sometimes the script is loaded very slow. Is there a way i can draw the graph with circle layout

I have tried to implement the fruchtermanReingold layout and also forceatlas2 but both of them have overlaps and the whole graph is cramped in one space

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];



// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Tweet").remove()
   }  

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

var j=JSON.parse('{{ jsn | escapejs }}');;
var img=document.getElementById("loading")
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod('neighbors', function(nodeId) {
    var k,
    neighbors = {},
    index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

    for (k in index)
      neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

    return neighbors;
    });

s = new sigma({
   graph: j,
   container: 'graph-container',  
   settings: {
   labelThreshold:10,

   }
  });

// Start the ForceAtlas2 algorithm:

  s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
    n.originalColor = n.color;
  });
  s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
    e.originalColor = e.color;
  });

  // When a node is clicked, we check for each node
  // if it is a neighbor of the clicked one. If not,
  // we set its color as grey, and else, it takes its
  // original color.
  // We do the same for the edges, and we only keep
  // edges that have both extremities colored.
  s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
  if(/^\d+$/.test(e.data.node.id)){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id","Tweet")
  div.setAttribute("align","center")
        document.getElementById("feed").insertBefore(div,document.getElementById("see"));   
  twttr.widgets.createTweet(e.data.node.id,div);
  twttr.widgets.load(div);

   }
   else{

   k=  s.graph.neighbors(e.data.node.id)

  modal.style.display = "block";
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("id","Tweet")
  div.setAttribute("align","center")
  document.getElementById("feed").insertBefore(div,document.getElementById("see")); 
  twttr.widgets.createTweet(Object.entries(k)[0][0],div);
  twttr.widgets.load(div);  
}
    var nodeId = e.data.node.id,
        toKeep = s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
    toKeep[nodeId] = e.data.node;

    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
      if (toKeep[n.id])
        n.color = n.originalColor;
      else
        n.color = '#eee';
    });

    s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
      if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target])
        e.color = e.originalColor;
      else
        e.color = '#eee';
    });

    // Since the data has been modified, we need to
    // call the refresh method to make the colors
    // update effective.
    s.refresh();
  });

  // When the stage is clicked, we just color each
  // node and edge with its original color.
  s.bind('clickStage', function(e) {
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
      n.color = n.originalColor;
    });

    s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
      e.color = e.originalColor;
    });

    // Same as in the previous event:
    s.refresh();
  });

var frListener = sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.configure(s, {
  iterations: 500,
  easing: 'quadraticInOut',
  duration: 800
  });

sigma.layouts.fruchtermanReingold.start(s);
```